# Uncaught TypeError: Object#<Object> has no method 'dispatchEvent'

Tags: javascript, drupal, typeerror, picasa

I'm trying to combine Drupal with [Picasa web integrator](http://www.paulvanroekel.nl/picasa-web-restyled/integrator/).

I have these 3 lines in the  section of my page.tpl.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fotos/js/jquery.slimbox2/jquery.slimbox2.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fotos/js/jquery.pwi.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
```

I also added this script to my head section, to test an album (the username and albumname are not important, I tested it offline with my username and album and that worked fine):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#container").pwi({
        username: 'My',
        maxresults: 5,
        mode: 'album',
        album: 'MyAlbum'
    });

});
</script>
```

Google Chrome gives me this error when I try it on my Drupal-page:

```
prototype.js:5733Uncaught TypeError: Object#<Object> has no method 'dispatchEvent'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal also comes with jQuery, and you cannot simply just add the later version in `<script>` tags. You can try using [Drupal's jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to get a more recent version, or try [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) (I suspect you will need it anyhow if you want to use Prototype).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are also loading [prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) on the page (used by `lightbox.js`, perhaps?, and that perhaps the `$` used by both jQuery and Prototype are conflicting. If you really need to use both Prototype and jQuery, look into using jQuery's `noConflict` mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/.

Comment: noConflict didn't help.

I somehow managed to solve the problem, by putting the <script> tags in my body, but there are still some problem using IE.
Link: chirowijkoersel.be/node/35

Comment: Problem solved, I had two scripts similar scripts running, the only difference was their file name. By removing one of them, the problem was solved.